# How can a Battlemind be made effective against flying/ranged monsters?

Tags: dnd-4e, battlemind

The Battlemind in D&D4e is extremely melee-focused.  Almost all of his powers are Melee powers, and most of his mark penalties rely on adjacency to the marked creature.  In most situations, this is not a huge issue, because he should have the support of a good Controller or other ranged combatant in his party.  Unfortunately, there are some cases in which he may be separated from that support, or those supporting characters are preoccupied with other tasks in the battle.

Is there anything that can/should be done to make a Battlemind more effective against flying/ranged monsters in these situations?

Comment: What level range? The answer at epic is probably much different from the answer at heroic.

Comment: Particularly looking at 1-4 right now, but bottom-to-top solutions would be nice to see.

Answer (score 4):

There are also some powers and enhancements that might help with reaching distant/airborne enemies.

#### Powers:

- [01] **Bull's Strength**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=11157)</sup> (Augment 2 for `Close blast 3`)
- [01] **Concussive Spike**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12419)</sup> (`Close blast 3`)
- [01] **Lodestone Lure**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13041)</sup> (`Melee 2`, augment 1 or 2 for `Melee 5`)
- [15] **Crushing Wave Strike**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13069)</sup> (Secondary attack with `Close blast 5`)
- [27] **Obsidian Shield**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13100)</sup> (`Close blast 3`)

#### Weapon enhancements:

- [02] **Psychokinetic Weapon**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=7372)</sup> (Augmentable item encounter power for a `ranged` basic attack, at least range 5/10; Augment 2: 1[W] extra damage)
- [05] **Fey Strike Weapon**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6942)</sup> (Item encounter power to make a melee basic attack as a `ranged 20` attack; item daily power teleporting a hit enemy 10 sq adjacent to you)

#### Misc enhancements:

- [03] **The Fading One - Ghostfoot**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=7926)</sup> (Item encounter power allows you to fly your speed until `EOT` when spending action point)
- [07] **Orb of Indisputable Gravity**<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=299)</sup> (Item daily power forces flying creatures down 10 sq when hit by an attack until `EONT`)

But other than that (or until you can afford them) never underestimate a simple crossbow or a bunch of javelins. A weak attack is better than no attack.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious choice would be to get a ranged weapon, either with a penalty, by multi-classing or to get a trained feat in that weapon.

Another option would be to have a magic item or weapon appropriate to this class grants a reach for melee combat.

Another would be to choose a feat which extends your reach by 1.

Remember there is a point where some classes have innate weaknesses and become dependent on other party members.

Answer (score 1):

Powers that can be used on a charge can be effective against ranged attackers up to twice your speed away (move your speed, charge your speed and make an attack). I don't know what the Battlemind has as far as options for those type of powers.

As far as flying enemies, either a ranged weapon or having an ally use a power that would knock them prone (in this case out of the air). Not sure there are many better options as far as this is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the situation.
Battleminds are at a distinct disadvantage against flying creatures. Your best course is probably to get between them and the party and ready an action. Using a ranged basic attack is also an option, but you'll be at a distinct relative penalty on the attack roll. Ready has the benefit of either letting you attack at full power when they come past, or forcing the enemy to work around your position.

Against ranged attacks, if the party can close the distance, that's the best move - just be aware that as the defender, your party members are depending on you to hold the line. You don't want to leave your vulnerable wizard exposed, for instance.

If you can't close the distance, you can try for ranged basic, but more important would be to position yourself in front and provide cover for your low-defense companions.